# Why are Character Marker Symbol Dialog not showing up in the Symbol Property Editor dialog?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I just installed ArcGIS 10.2.1 on a brand new machine and for some reason Character Marker Symbols are not loading into the Symbol Property Editor.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?  Is there a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize for ansering my own question this quick but I checked on the ESRI forums and a similar problem is documented there: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9869-symbol-property-editor-will-not-display-character-marker-symbols

The culprit seems to be ATI video card with their application called Hydravision.  I have an AMD FirePro W7000 (FireGL V) but it also does have HydraVision.

The solution is to disable the disable the "enable dialog repositioning" option.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different solution that worked for me:

1. Right click on desktop
2. Under AMD FirePRO, Select HydraVision
3. Select Desktop Manager
4. Uncheck Enable Desktop Manager

Step 4 is also where you can disable the "enable dialog repositioning"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

"If you are on a Win7 Computer go to:

C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates

and either delete or rename the normal.mxt

ArcMap will take a bit longer to open next time (has to recreate that mxt) but the styles will reappear."

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 10.3 recently and had the same problem. My solution was to do the following:

Customize

Toolbars

Click "Labeling" toolbar

On the labeling toolbar, click the drop-down arrow next to labeling.

Scroll down to Use Maplex Label Engine and click to turn it off.

It will give you a screen prompt asking are you sure you want to turn it off, click yes.

It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 10.3. I've found two workarounds (but I don't know why they work):

Workaround 1 (the first one I've found):

1. Navigate, in Windows Explorer, to C:\Users\ [current user]\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap\Templates
2. Double-click normal.mxt (ArcMap opens with a blank project, with styles loaded)
3. Open any other map document from the File menu

Workaround 2 (the second workaround I've found):

1. Open ArcMap
2. In the "Getting Started" dialog, select New Maps / My Templates / Blank map; check "Do not show this dialog in the future"; and click "Ok"
3. Open any other map document from the File menu
4. (Next time you execute ArcMap, you will start in a blank project with styles loaded and can open any other map document from the File menu)

(Excuse my English)

Answer (score 0):

O problema era a placa de vídeo ATI com a sua aplicação chamada HydraVision. (**The problem was the ATI video card with their application called HydraVision.**)

A solução que funcionou para mim: (**The solution that worked for me:**)

- Botão direito do mouse na área de trabalho,(**Right click on desktop,**)
- Seleccione AMD Catalyst Control Center, (**Select AMD Catalyst Control Center,**)
- Seleccione Áreas de Trabalho e Monitores, (**Select Desktops and Displays,**)
- Seleccionar HydraVision, (**Select HydraVision,**)
- Seleccionar Gerenc. da Área de Trabalho, (**Select Desktop Manager,**)
- Desmarque a opção Ativar Gerenciador da áerea de trabalho. (**Uncheck Enable Desktop Manager.**)

Problema resolvido. (**Problem solved.**)

Comment: Please do not post in Portuguese.