# ArcGIS No font options for Character symbol

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, windows-7

I can't get the font options to display when trying to use character symbol in ArcMap. This problem is local to my machine only. See screenshot below.

ArcMap 10.2.2 & Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit

[image]

Comment: If this is happening on only your machine, and the problem has survived a reboot, then I would consider an uninstall/re-install of ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.  It may sound drastic, but is likely to take less time than troubleshooting.

Comment: Ensure that all remnants of previous versions have been removed before re-installing. There is a utility to check for this in previous versions which may help. Also, consider other software, specifically desktop publishing software, that may have other fonts that Esri doesn't like - I haven't seen this issue arise for a very long time but it's still possible that an installed font is incompatible with ArcGis.

Comment: Question is answered [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85840/why-are-character-marker-symbol-dialog-not-showing-up-in-the-symbol-property-edi)